# Extracting Video Data From Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are looking to create a very simple application that will be able to go through a page and collect public information. Atm we do this manually but as the list grows this is just not going to be scalable. Is there a way we can use the API to collect information like, Video Title, Date And Time Posted, thumbnail, Views, Likes, Comments. Game Played (If any) etc.

All of this we can manually collect, We tried using a scraper but quickly found out FB do not like that.

We have tried scraping, but got in trouble from facebook for it